# twitter streaming api - set filter in http post request (apache httpcomponents)

Tags: java, http, httpwebrequest, twitter

I'm trying out the twitter streaming api. I could succesfully filter tweets by using curl, as stated [here](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Streaming-API-Documentation#Methods):

```
curl -d @tracking http://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json -u <user>:<pass>
```

where `tracking` is a plain file with the content:

```
track=Berlin
```

Now I tried to do the same thing in JavaSE, using Apache's HTTPComponents:

```
    UsernamePasswordCredentials creds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(<user>, <pass>);
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, creds);
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json");
    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();

    params = params.setParameter("track", "Berlin");
    httpPost.setParams(params);

    try {
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            String t;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream));
            while(true) {
                t = br.readLine();
                if(t != null) {                        
                    linkedQueue.offer(t);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
    }
    finally{
        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
```

When I run that, I get:

`No filter parameters found. Expect at least one parameter: follow track`

as a single entry in my `linkedQueue`. Seems the api wants the parameter in a different form, but cannot find any hint in the documentation. Can somebody share some experiences with the api or see any other problem with the code? Thanks!

**EDIT** 
Putting the filter parameter into the params was a bad idea. As it's post data, it needs to be defined as an `Entity` before the request is being made:

```
        StringEntity postEntity = new StringEntity("track=Berlin", "UTF-8");
        postEntity.setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        httpPost.setEntity(postEntity);
```

That's what I was doing wrong. Thanks Brian!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you need to post the data as the *contents* of your HTTP post. The man page for `curl -d` says:

> (HTTP) Sends the specified data in a
>   POST request to the HTTP server, in
>   the same way that a browser does when
>   a user has filled in an HTML form and
>   presses the submit button. This will
>   cause curl to pass the data to the
>   server using the content-type
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

so I believe you have to set that content type and put the contents of the tracking file in the body of your post.